# Multithreading in Java and database

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I have a simple program. The main idea is that I have a list of names stored in MySQL database and I want to do some operations on these names concurrently, but of course, each thread should work in a separate name. The next thread should work on the next name that taken by the previous thread. I created thread pool, I create new threads inside the loop and then execute the runnable so the operations on that names performed. In this example, the operation is printing the name that is selected from DB. The program is skipping some names from the database, and repeated the last name 6 times. What is wrong in my program? I'm still new to threads, please excuse my mistakes.

This is the main function:

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    public static volatile ResultSet resultSet = null;
    private static Statement statement = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException 

    {
        DBConnection.ConnectDB(); //connect to database


          statement = DBConnection.con.createStatement();
          resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select Name from schema.table1"); //select statement

          String name = null;


           // create ExecutorService to manage threads 
          ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3 );

          // create and name each runnable  
          while(resultSet.next()) 
             {
                 name=resultSet.getString("Name");
                 MyRunnable task1 = new  MyRunnable( name);
                 threadExecutor.execute( task1 );
          }


        // This will make the executor accept no new threads
        // and finish all existing threads in the queue

             threadExecutor.shutdown();
        // Wait until all threads are finish
        while (! threadExecutor.isTerminated()) {

        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }
}
```

And the MyRunnable class:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException;

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
private static String nn;


MyRunnable (String ss)  { synchronized (this) { 
    this.nn=ss;
}
}


public void run() 
{

    System.out.println("hello "+ nn);
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is certainly one issue.  Remove the static.

```
private static String nn;
```

becomes

```
private String nn;
```

Comment: It looks like this must be the problem... @JuryA, you should accept this one!

Comment: @tjg184: After fixing private static String nn; I got the names displayed after they have been retrieved from the database without duplicates but not in the correct order they are stored in the DB. I got them as this order: 1 – 2 – 3 – 4 – 5 – 7 – 6 – 9 – 8 – 11 – 10 – 13 – 12 – 15 – 14 – 17 – 16 – 19 – 18 - 20 while the correct one (from 1 to 20) Is this normally what should happen with threads or there is something wrong ?

Comment: Another thing, the problem that I have is that I have to read a long list of names and process each one which takes time & I used threads to make this fast. Is the method I used above correct (retrieve the name from DB and assign it to each thread using the constructor)? Or is it possible to make each thread reads names by itself in a loop so each thread has its own loop to read names? But each thread should retrieve the name that comes next to the one that the last thread retrieved.

Comment: To your first question, threads are not guaranteed to run in any specific order in general.  This is likely why you're seeing the numbers printed out of order.  You also do not need synchronized (this).  If I were doing this and needed threads, I would read the data first from the table, then process the data later using threads if you choose.  I think you have two different concepts going on and this will make for a much better solution.  I'm also not sure of the thread safety of reading from a ResultSet.  I could see several issues there.

Comment: If I didn't use synchronized(this), will Java manage that not two thread read the same vale from the result set??

Comment: It appears you are reading the resultSet before creating the thread.  Since you've removed the static reference to nn, each instance will have a copy of name to do whatever it needs.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, this block:

```
while (! threadExecutor.isTerminated()) {
}
```

Should read:

```
while (! threadExecutor.isTerminated()) {
   try {
       threadExecutor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECOND);
   }
   catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // you have to determine if someone can interrupt your wait
        // for the full termination of the executor, but most likely,
        // you'll do nothing here and swallow the exception, or rethrow
        // it in a RuntimeException
   }
}
```

You should never do a busy wait like you're doing.  You'll use unnecessary CPU cycles, and take processing time away from the actual threads in the pool.

Comment: Ok. But your code seems that the waiting time is 1 sec. only ?? How can you grant that all threads exited in 1 sec. before you exit the main thread ?

Comment: That's why there's a while loop.  You could always set the wait time to a day or something, and avoid the while loop if you'd like.

Comment: I used to call the get() method on a list of Future object to understand if the thread has terminated. Do you think your solution is better? thanks

Comment: You can use Future.get if you'd like, but there's two downsides to that:   First, you have to collect up all the futures you've submitted and call get on each one of them.  Second, if you happen to call threadExecutor.execute(Runnable) then you don't have a future object.  It's safer to ask the threadpool when it's completely shutdown and use Future.get when you actually want the value, or if you have a long living thread pool (ie, lives outside the scope of the individual method).